# Get data from Cloud Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image: Picture]

I need to get data from Firestore Firebase, I need to get the value of field "Company" from "employer" collection -> "TH17..." document. I try some things but it didnt work.

How I can do this?

I try this:

```
docref = db.collection("employer").document("TH17...");
        docref.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    if (document.exists()) {
                        String p= document.getData().toString();
                        Log.d("TAG", "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
                    } 
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Show what you have tried. So that the answer is much more focused on the issue you are facing

Comment: @PavanVarma I add what i tried

Comment: small hunch did you add 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
in Manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to get the value of field "company" from "employer" collection -> "TH17..." document.

To solve this, please change the following lines of code:

```
String p= document.getData().toString();
Log.d("TAG", "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
```

to

```
String company = document.getString("Company");
Log.d("TAG", "Company: " + company);
```

The result in your logcat will be:

```
Company: Test
```